# Awk leave blank lines

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following `awk` command to select the first two columns from `file_a` and print them in `file_b`.

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' file_a > file_b
```

`file_a` is tab separated and has some blank lines that I want to keep. When running the above command, although, the blank lines are printed as \t\n, and I want them to keep being just \n. What do I need to change in the `awk` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{print (NF ? $1"\t"$2 : $0)}' file_a > file_b
```

Comment: I feel proud of myself: I imagined almost the same solution :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {if(NF) print $1,$2; else print}' file
```

or

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NF{print $1,$2; next}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter:

```
awk '/^$/;/./{print $1"\t"$2}' file_a > file_b
```

But this won't work in special cases like when the first or second column is empty or column data contains spaces. In order to handle your tabular data correctly, use this command:

```
awk -F"\t" '/^$/;/./{print $1"\t"$2}' file_a > file_b
```